Creaky sound while pedaling
After some rainy rides my bike developed this creaky sound.
https://youtube.com/shorts/w0bhjAHORoU
I took mine SRAM Red PF30 bottom bracket apart, cleaned up the bearings. I have ultrasonic machine so washed them with a bike degreaser. Dried. Put new fresh HPG-1 grease.
Assembled everything back. Used supergrip compound when installed a bottom bracket. It is press fit. I have a special tool that lets to put everything back nice and precise.
After all this service I still have that annoying sound when I apply extra force or pedal uphill.
Could this be chain? I checked length - it is within norms.
Also I suspect front shifting to be a little bit misaligned because when I shift to the larger gear it might not always shift right away.
It didn't happen before I serviced the bottom bracket. I double checked everything, I didn't loose anything and everything looks nice and tight.
Should I take pedals apart? Those are Assioma power meters so I slightly concerned if I will change calibration.
Any advice?

I had to replace the bottom bracket and use pressfit retaining compound.
Please be aware that you will need an adhesive primer that works with the compound. The retaining compound holds very well so you will be in trouble if don't use the primer.
From what I was able to understand that ceramic bearings has a scuff and that produced this terrible creaky sound.
Also I noticed that my cassette got worn out too so this is also contributed a little bit.
I wish SRAM sold individual cogs for the cassette so it can be more sustainably serviced.
